# How do i fix this specific null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, null

I am writing an  object class to count number of each letters and when i run my test code it shows me a null pointer exception when "abc" is passed.i cant figure out why. there is no error is test code but there is some mistake in my object class.

```
public class LetterInventory {

   private static final int COUNTER = 26;
   private int size = 0;
   private int[] inventory;

   public LetterInventory() {
    inventory = new int [COUNTER];
 }
   public LetterInventory (String data) {
      data = data.toLowerCase();
      for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
         int charPosition = data.charAt(i) - 'a';
         if(charPosition >= 0 && charPosition <  COUNTER) {
             inventory[charPosition]++;
             size++;
         } 
      }
   }
```

Comment: The fix is the same for all NPE: figure out what's null and assign it to a non-null reference.  The stack trace tells you the line number in the file that produced it.  Isn't that a good enough hint?

Comment: Well, it is not very clever to initialize `inventory` in one constructor and use it in another one. You can't call both, so either you're not able to count anything or `inventory` remains `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize the array in the second constructor.

```
public LetterInventory(String data) {
    inventory = new int[COUNTER]; // <= initialization was missing
    data = data.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = data.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if (charPosition >= 0 && charPosition < COUNTER) {
            inventory[charPosition]++;
            size++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of initialising it in two places, invoke the other constructor: `this();`. See [DRY](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: But, how and where do i use this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment so here you go:

```
public LetterInventory(String data) {
    this();
    //inventory = new int[COUNTER]; // <= initialization was missing

    data = data.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = data.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if (charPosition >= 0 && charPosition < COUNTER) {
        inventory[charPosition]++;
        size++;
    }
}
```